# Importing notepad data to excel (difficult split)

Tags: excel, powershell, notepad, data-transform

I want to transfer this data from notepad to excel and split it into columns
but the problem is that the data (i didn't make this) doesnt split on a delimiter.
All the data looks like variations of the following this

```
Header: "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" ... "n"
rows:   "1" "sgvgs-dvfds" "" "0.0" "d'/.d" ... "m"
```

Everything is contained within quotations. Does anyone know in excel on how to make it happen or even through powershell?

Comment: I may be missing something, but isn't space " " a delimiter in the data you have shown (assuming there are the same number of columns in 'rows' as there are in 'Header')?

Comment: Is that really what the text file looks like? Labels `Header:` and `rows: ` in front of each line? If not, please open the file in notepad and copy the first couple of lines. Paste that in the question.

Comment: "" <- essentially sometimes there will only be two quotation marks without nothing in between to signify no data for that column. No the Header: and rows: dont actually appear. I added that to show you. I cant paste the info because its my work data.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: As already mentioned, It looks like space delimited to me. Even with two quotes with nothing in them. Why don't you try space delimited in excel

Answer (score 2):

If that is really what the file looks like, you can convert it to a CSV format that Excel will understand like this:

```
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\WeirdFormat.csv' -Raw) -replace '(?m)^(Header|rows):\s+' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' | 
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\ExcelCanOpenThis.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

You should now have a csv file that will open in Excel if you double-click it.

If not, please provide a better example of the input file showing **exactly** what it looks like.

Regex details:

```
(?m)               Match the remainder of the regex with the options: ^ and $ match at line breaks (m)
^                  Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
(                  Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
                   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      Header       Match the characters “Header” literally
   |               Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      rows         Match the characters “rows” literally
)                 
:                  Match the character “:” literally
\s                 Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   +               Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

---

As from your comment, the `Header:` and `rows:` are **not** in the file.
That makes it a lot easier and simply do:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\InputFile.csv -Delimiter ' ' | 
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\ExcelCanOpenThis.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

Aren't we overthinking it? The ultimate destination the original poster wants is in Excel, so why involve PowerShell at all?

Using Excel:

1. Select "From Text/CSV" on the Data tab
2. Select & open the file
3. In the dialog that opens, set delimiter to Space, then click Load
4. Bingo, the Excel data that OP wants (and it handles empty columns properly)

Comment: Agreed. Why choose a complicated solution when there is a simple one